# Display Repeatation Item in ListView after three Item on Scrolling in android?

Tags: android, listview

I want to fill Listview but But Repeat only imgLike,imgComments,txtLikeUnlike and txtComments from all Items. Because I using array for imgLike,imgComments,txtLikeUnlike and txtComments for get (fetch)selected Position. what is mistake in my code please guide me.

My code,
/** Adapter Class */

```
public class Adapter1 extends BaseAdapter {
        ImageView imgImage = null,imgUnlike[] = null, imgLike[] = null,imgComments[] = null, imgShare[] = null;
        TextView txtId = null,txtLikeUnlike[] = null, txtComments[] = null; 

            public ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> arr = null;
            Context context = null;
            LayoutInflater layoutInflater = null;
            HashMap<String, String> getData = new HashMap<String, String>();

            public Adapter1(Context context,
                    ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> arr) {

                this.context = context;
                this.arr = arr;
                layoutInflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);
                this.imgUnlike = new ImageView[arr.size()];
                this.imgLike = new ImageView[arr.size()];
                this.imgComments = new ImageView[arr.size()];
                this.imgShare = new ImageView[arr.size()];
                this.txtLikeUnlike = new TextView[arr.size()];
                this.txtComments = new TextView[arr.size()];
            }

            @Override
            public int getCount() {
                return arr.size();
            }

            @Override
            public Object getItem(int position) {
                return arr.get(position);
            }

            @Override
            public long getItemId(int position) {
                return position;
            }

            @SuppressLint("InflateParams")
            @Override
            public View getView(final int position, View convertView,
                    ViewGroup parent) {
                View row = null;
                if (convertView == null) {
                    LayoutInflater inflater = ((Activity) context)
                            .getLayoutInflater();
                    row = inflater.inflate(R.layout.list_item, parent,
                            false);
                } else {
                     row = convertView;
                }
                /** Initialize Widgets */
                /** Imageview */

                imgImage = (ImageView) row
                        .findViewById(R.id.imgImage);

                imgUnlike[position] = (ImageView) row
                        .findViewById(R.id.imgUnlike);

                imgLike[position] = (ImageView) row
                        .findViewById(R.id.imgLike);

                imgComments[position] = (ImageView) row
                        .findViewById(R.id.imgComments);

                imgShare[position] = (ImageView) row
                        .findViewById(R.id.imgShare);

                /** TextView */
                txttId = (TextView) row
                        .findViewById(R.id.txtId);
                txtLikeUnlike[position] = (TextView) row
                        .findViewById(R.id.txtLikeUnlike);
                txtComments[position] = (TextView) row
                        .findViewById(R.id.txtComments);

                getData = arr.get(position);

                txtId.setText(getData.get(Fragment1.TAG_ID));

                imgUnlike[position]
                        .setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

                            @Override
                            public void onClick(View v) {
                                imgUnlike[position]
                                        .setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
                                imgLike[position]
                                        .setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

                                getCurrentPosition = position;
                            }
                        });

                imgLike[position].setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View v) {
                        imgNewsFeedLike[position].setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
                        imgNewsFeedUnlike[position].setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

                    }
                });

                row.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View v) {

                        Intent intent = new Intent(getActivity(),
                                Detail.class);
                        startActivity(intent);
                    }
                });
                return row;
            }
```

xml file is,

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/masterLayout"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_margin="@dimen/five_dp" >

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imgImage"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="150dp"
        android:layout_below="@+id/imgBlueStrip"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_margin="10dp"
        android:background="@null"
        android:contentDescription="@string/content_description"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher" />

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_below="@+id/imgImage"
        android:background="@drawable/strip"
        android:baselineAligned="false"
        android:gravity="center_vertical"
        android:orientation="horizontal" >

        <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1" >

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/imgUnlike"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
                android:layout_centerInParent="true"
                android:contentDescription="@string/content_description"
                android:src="@drawable/unlike" />

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/imgLike"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
                android:layout_centerVertical="true"
                android:contentDescription="@string/content_description"
                android:src="@drawable/like"
                android:visibility="invisible" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/txtLikeUnlike"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
                android:layout_marginLeft="2dp"
                android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/imgUnlike"
                android:background="@drawable/get_notification_bg"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:padding="2dp"
                android:textColor="@color/white"
                android:textSize="10sp" />
        </RelativeLayout>

        <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1" >

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/imgComments"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
                android:layout_centerInParent="true"
                android:contentDescription="@string/content_description"
                android:src="@drawable/comments" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/txtComments"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/imgComments"
                android:background="@drawable/get_"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:padding="2dp"
                android:textColor="@android:color/white"
                android:textSize="10sp" />
        </RelativeLayout>

        <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1" >

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/imgShare"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
                android:layout_centerInParent="true"
                android:contentDescription="@string/content_description"
                android:src="@drawable/share" />
        </RelativeLayout>
    </LinearLayout>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/txtId"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
        android:text="id" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imgBlueStrip"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_below="@+id/txtId"
        android:contentDescription="@string/content_description"
        android:src="@drawable/blue_strip" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

My Layout Display Like this,[image]

Comment: you should use holder for that..

Comment: @Slade If I using ViewHolder then How to define array in Constructor Like this.imgLike = new ImageView[arr.size()];

Comment: you dont need to change constructor for that..refer this link..http://theopentutorials.com/tutorials/android/listview/android-custom-listview-with-image-and-text-using-baseadapter/

Comment: @Slade ohk Thanx I can Try it and Then After I tell you, What Happen?

Comment: @Slade how to initialize imgLike array in constructor If I using ViewHolder?

Comment: viewholder is for only set values in views.. so you dont need to initialize there. your code is fine. just use holder as per that link..

Comment: @Slade Ok but I Must be change for Like and UnLike(Thumb Image) so I need to Selected position for imgLike and Initialize it.